# How to select dataframe values by a list of indices and columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, let's use this example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [5,6,3,4], 'B': [1,2,3,5]})
df
   A  B
0  5  1
1  6  2
2  3  3
3  4  5
```

and I have a list of columns (by index) that I want to select, let's say:

```
list=['A','B','B','A']
```

What I want to obtain is `[5,2,3,4]`, a series if possible. How can I do this?
I tried with masks, but I couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use lookup:

```
df.values[range(len(df)), df.columns.get_indexer_for(l)]
```

---

```
array([5, 2, 3, 4], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Upvote for using `.values`

Comment: Haha! Thanks @PanwenWang I always prefer `.values` over `.to_numpy`. `.values` sounds simpler to me :-)

Comment: No, I meant using `.values` or `.to_numpy()` to avoid looping over `df.loc` or `df.iloc`.

Comment: @PanwenWang I see.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a lookup using numpy advanced indexing:

```
import numpy as np
idx, cols = pd.factorize(lst)
out = out = df.reindex(cols, axis=1).to_numpy()[range(len(df)), idx].tolist()
```

Output:

```
[5, 2, 3, 4]
```